# Make hexagon shape with border, rounded corners and transparent background

Tags: css, svg, css-shapes

I want to make a hexagonal shape with border, rounded corners and transparent background in CSS3 like in this image:

[image: rounded hexagon with border]

I can't make this with rounded corners and border.

My code is here:

```css
#hexagon-circle {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 10em;
  height: 17.32em;
  border-radius: 1em/.5em;
  background: red;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#hexagon-circle:before {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
  -ms-transform: rotate(60deg);  /* IE 9 */
  transform: rotate(60deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}

#hexagon-circle:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ */
  -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg);  /* IE 9 */
  transform: rotate(-60deg); /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera */
}
```

```html
<div id="hexagon-circle"></div>
```

Comment: Have you Googled `make hexagon shape with border and rounded corners in css`?

Comment: Tnx for attention...I try that but it isn't helpful..how can i set border for this  : http://jsfiddle.net/yR7zt/4/   ...... my major problem is set border for this....solid border set is not good idea,,!

Comment: I found a sample of that thing i want --- I want thing same this : http://respooonsive.com/dash/demo/index-image.html

Comment: @miladhp: Is the inner part of your shape transparent (or) will it have a colored/image as fill?

Comment: @web-tiki  --- It isn't my target--- now , how can I add border for this hexagonal ?? it is my problem.

Comment: @Harry it is transparent.. I want to add a  text in it..

Comment: Looks like you can make it with rounded corners

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hexagon with rounded corners are complex shapes to create and I usually recommend using SVG for creating them. The need for a transparent background makes it even more better suited for SVG. With SVG you can get better control over the shape, its curves etc and you don't have to add a lot of extra (unnecessary) elements to your markup also.

All that is needed for creating this shape with SVG is to use a single `path` element along with a few `L` (line) and `A` (arc) commands. The `L` (line) command basically draws a line from point 1 to point 2 whereas the `A` (arc) command draws an arc of the specified radius (the first two values immediately following the `A` command).

You can read more about the SVG `path` element and its commands in [this MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths).

```css
svg {
  height: 200px;
  width: 240px;
}
path {
  stroke: #777;
  fill: none;
}

body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 120 100'>
  <path d='M38,2 
           L82,2 
           A12,12 0 0,1 94,10 
           L112,44 
           A12,12 0 0,1 112,56
           L94,90       
           A12,12 0 0,1 82,98
           L38,98
           A12,12 0 0,1 26,90
           L8,56
           A12,12 0 0,1 8,44
           L26,10
           A12,12 0 0,1 38,2' />
</svg>
```

If you still want to use CSS, you could follow the approach used by [jbutler483](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3436942/jbutler483) in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/71bqazgd/10/) of his. (*I have appended the code from that fiddle also into this answer to avoid link rot problems*)

```css
.roundHex {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 180px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 1s;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: black;
  border-bottom-color: black;
}
.roundHex:before,
.roundHex:after {
  content: "";
  border: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.roundHex:before {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.roundHex:after {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="roundHex"></div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot Harry...svg is best idea for do this...it is easy and best way for do it..

Answer (score 2):

I made a codepen where you can customise side length and border radius: https://codepen.io/shreyansqt/pen/qBjprWE

**HTML:**

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <path id="hexagon" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

**JS:**

```js
const getHexagonPathData = () => {
  // #################### x1,y0 ####################
  // ############## xc1,yc0 # xc2,yc0 ##############
  // ###############################################
  // ###############################################
  // #### xc0,yc1 ##################### xc3,yc1 ####
  // ## x0,y1 ############################# x2,y1 ##
  // ## x0,yc2 ########################### x2,yc2 ##
  // ###############################################
  // ###############################################
  // ## x0,yc3 ########################### x2,yc3 ##
  // ## x0,y2 ############################# x2,y2 ##
  // #### xc0,yc4 ##################### xc3,yc4 ####
  // ###############################################
  // ###############################################
  // ############## xc1,yc5 # xc2,yc5 ##############
  // #################### x1,y3 ####################

  const sin = (deg) => Math.sin((deg * Math.PI) / 180);
  const cos = (deg) => Math.cos((deg * Math.PI) / 180);

  const borderRadius = 6;
  const sideLength = 80;
  const x0 = 0;
  const y0 = 0;

  const x1 = sideLength * cos(30);
  const y1 = sideLength * sin(30);

  const xc1 = x1 - borderRadius * cos(30);
  const yc0 = borderRadius * sin(30);
  const xc2 = x1 + borderRadius * cos(30);

  const x2 = 2 * x1;
  const y2 = y1 + sideLength;

  const xc3 = x2 - borderRadius * cos(30);
  const yc1 = y1 - borderRadius * sin(30);
  const yc2 = y1 + borderRadius;

  const y3 = y2 + y1;

  const yc3 = y2 - borderRadius;
  const yc4 = y2 + borderRadius * sin(30);

  const yc5 = y3 - borderRadius * sin(30);
  const xc0 = borderRadius * cos(30);

  return `
        M ${xc1},${yc0}
        Q ${x1},${y0} ${xc2},${yc0}

        L ${xc3},${yc1}
        Q ${x2},${y1} ${x2},${yc2}

        L ${x2},${yc3}
        Q ${x2},${y2} ${xc3},${yc4}

        L ${xc2},${yc5}
        Q ${x1},${y3} ${xc1},${yc5}
        
        L ${xc0},${yc4}
        Q ${x0},${y2} ${x0},${yc3}
        
        L ${x0},${yc2}
        Q ${x0},${y1} ${xc0},${yc1}
        Z
      `;
};

const hexagon = document.getElementById("hexagon");

hexagon.setAttribute("d", getHexagonPathData());
```

Comment: This is a cool piece of code, though the question was asking how to do this (maybe without the mouse interactions) in CSS specifically.

Comment: @P.Moloney Your point is valid and you are technically correct, but it's also worth noting that the OP added a comment to the accepted answer stating that the non-CSS solution provided (i.e. using `<svg>`) was the _"easy and best way"_.

Comment: Incredible @shreyansqt